# How to assign a property of an actor to a view controller property?

Tags: swift, actor

I have an actor like this:
I want to assign a value from the NewsCache actor to the ViewController, but it gives the following error:

**Main actor-isolated property 'cache_data' can not be mutated from a Sendable closure**

```
actor NewsCache {
    var current_news_on_fetch  : [String:Bool] = [:]
    var news_dict : [String:NewsFeedPageStruct] = [:]
    var time_dict_news : [String:String] = [:]
    var ordered_uuid_news : [String] = []
}
class ViewController : UIViewController  {
   var cache_data : [String : NewsFeedPageStruct] = [:]
   var actor_news = NewsCache()

 func setData(){
        print("Below is the problem")
        Task.detached { [self] in

            self.cache_data = await self.actor_news.get_uuids()//this is the line which produces the error
            await self.reloadSnapshot(hash_news: str_arr.0) //this is in the MainActor
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MainActor.run` to run a closure on the main actor. But `MainActor.run` takes a synchronous (non-`async`) closure, so you'll want to call `get_uuids` before calling `MainActor.run`:

```
func setData_0(){
    Task.detached {
        let cache_data = await self.actor_news.get_uuids()
        await MainActor.run {
            self.cache_data = cache_data
            self.reloadSnapshot()
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to wrap the assignment to `cache_data` in a `@MainActor`-bound closure that you execute immediately:

```
func setData_1(){
    Task.detached {
        await { @MainActor in
            self.cache_data = await self.actor_news.get_uuids()
        }()
        await self.reloadSnapshot()
    }
}
```